# Multiple selectors in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there a way to have multiple selectors in Ext JS 4?

I know that in JQuery you can do it like

```
$('.selector1,.selector2').click(function(){
   //..
});
```

I have tried the same approach, but it seems is not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the same approach works for me in [Ext.DomQuery.select](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.DomQuery-method-select)

```
Ext.DomQuery.select('div,input')
```

will select all divs and inputs on page

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways that you can do this:

- Include the `jQuery` Adapter provided along with the `Ext JS`
  distribution and then use `jQuery` itself!
- Use `Ext.query('.selector1,.selector2')`. Takes selectors similar to `jQuery`. List can be found
  [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.DomQuery)